# How can I start to debug external displays not being detected?

Tags: 14.04, external-monitor

I'm running 14.04 on a HP ProBook 650. It has the built in graphics card and standalone;

```
Integrated: Intel® HD Graphics 4600 
Discrete: AMD RadeonTM HD 8 8750M (128-bit) w/1 GB GDDR5
```

On a fresh install of 14.04 I was able to use a Docking Station to drive one DVI external monitor, the display port to drive another external monitor as well as the builtin 15" screen, making a total of 3. That worked out of the box, no configuration required.

After 4 weeks of getting it setup, no single action seem to have killed both external displays but it seems to be from a combination of

- removing the laptop from the dock
- unplugging the display port
- pulling standard Ubuntu updates
- configuring the displays through Settings > Displays

have rendered the display port monitor then docking station monitor undetectable.

None of the external displays are detected at all any more and as far as I'm aware I've not messed with any display config / software other that what is mentioned.

Sorry to be rather vague on details of the displays becoming undetectable but it really was as random as it seems.

I'm really just after some advice on where to start to try and debug this. So far I've just tried

- enabling the 3rd party drivers that were offered through Software & Updates
- poking around in the Catalyst application and enabling "Rendering and Additional Displays" in the Switchable Graphics section.

I'm a software dev with a bit of commandline fu, so any guidance of that nature appreciated too.

Comment: After attaching the external monitors, what does the output of `xrandr` look like?

Comment: This could be an issue with the catalyst drivers. The docks are just port replicators for the intel GPU as far as im aware. If your using the catalyst stuff it might not be picking up the monitors plugged into dock because its running off the AMD card...? GPU switching is still pretty poor in Linux. I would suggest just running off intel graphics unless you need the extra grunt.

Comment: @sumwale 
    `~$xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768       60.1*+   40.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)`

Comment: @LinuxBill Thanks for your comments. How would I go about controlling what the displays are running off?

Comment: Got one step in the right direction. Removed all `xorg.conf*`'s from /etc/X11 and that then enabled the monitor connected to the dock. It's performance as a second monitor is pretty poor (laggy screen refresh) so the goal has narrowed slightly to just focus on getting the Radeon GPU (connected to the display port) to drive a secondary monitor.

Comment: I've so far not had any success getting the fglrx drivers driving the Radeo GPU yet, mostly I've just broken lightdm / X in the process. I've also found ~/.config/monitors.xml - although it isn't directly related to my problem, worth mentioning it's existence for anyone else. This is very painful.

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: @Fabby No thanks, traded in my laptop at work for a desktop with a dual port card which is much better behaved. Thanks for the follow up though.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the comments, `xrandr`often provides some helpful information, as does the `/var/log/syslog` log file and `~/.config/monitors.xml`. And I'm glad you are now set up with a better behaved computer.

(But I'm sure there are other sites providing better debugging tools and insights....)